# is 'ClassName.class' in Java same as '[ClassName::class]' in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dagger

On the Android dev page, in the Dagger section,

`NetworkModule.class` in Java code is written as `[NetworkModule::class]` in Kotlin code.

1. I thought `NetworkModule.class` in Java should be `NetworkModule::class.java` in Kotlin, isn't it?
2. why use the square brackets(`[]`)? I think it's the same as `get`, but why do we need it?

I was reading this: https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/dagger-android#java

In the 'Dagger Modules' section,

Java code:

```
@Component(modules = NetworkModule.class)
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    ...
}
```

the same code written in Kotlin:

```
@Component(modules = [NetworkModule::class])
interface ApplicationComponent {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the [array literal syntax](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#arrays-as-annotation-parameters) supported only in annotations, added in Kotlin 1.2. You can use it to pass arrays of things to annotations. So `[NetworkModule::class]` is actually an array containing a single element, that being `NetworkModule::class`.

The Kotlin code translated to Java would be:

```
@Component(modules = { NetworkModule.class })
interface ApplicationComponent {
    ...
}
```

It's just that the `{}` brackets can be omitted in Java, when there is a single element in the array. However, you can't just write `NetworkModule::class` in Kotlin. You have to explicitly say that it's an array, using ways such as `[]`, or `arrayOf`, unless it's the `value` parameter, in which case it is translated as `vararg`.

In general, `NetworkModule.class` in Java should be translated to `NetworkModule::class` when in an annotation. But note that this is of type `KClass`. If you want a `java.lang.Class`, add `.java`.

Comment: I think (but can't find documentation to confirm) that in the world of annotation parameters, Kotlin maps between KClass and Class just like how it maps between several other classes in standard code.

Comment: @Tenfour04 You mean [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#constructors)? "If you need to specify a class as an argument of an annotation, use a Kotlin class (KClass). The Kotlin compiler will automatically convert it to a Java class"

Comment: What a clear explanation! Thanks a lot. So, the reason we don't have to add `.java` is that Kotlin compiler automatically convert it to a Java class, when it comes to arguments of an annotation? 
Thanks, Sweeper and Tenfour04 :)